# Site Magento 1.7.2 is down for Malware reason

Tags: magento-1.7, security

I cannot access the site in Chrome and Mozilla. In internet Explore it is OK. It shows me "Security error->The site ahead contains malware". When I try to open it. The site is melvinflex.com. Is there any way how to solve this by not upgrade it to any other version because I have some bad experience with magento in version upgrades.Thank you.

Comment: Could you please check all the files , any code written in it like , "eval(" or any malicious code. Remove all the codes . Give the proper permission to the site files and folders.

Comment: @Lorenc  Take Backup of your website (Files and DB) . Download Magento 1.7.2 and replace the files using FILEZILLA or in the Hosting Panel. Then try to Debug the downloaded code where it effected.

Comment: I removed some js scripts  in backend and there are a lot of files effected.

Answer (score 0):

Scan your site on `magereport.com` to identify any missing security patches and to determine if it has been infected with known malware strains.

You can install all missing patches and test store functionality in a non-production environment.

Remove any suspicious script added via backend.

However I recommend you to upgrade magento to its latest version which will include all the patches implemented.

Comment: I just removed some js scripts in backend and there are some patches that miss .